# Python2, DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python

I installed the anaconda3(64-bit)and set two conda environments: py27 and py36.
when I import numpy in python2.7, I come across this problem:

> DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Error Traceback:

```
runfile('E:/master/project/try1.py', wdir='E:/master/project')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-2-5f6896d42b49>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('E:/master/project/try1.py', wdir='E:/master/project')
  File "C:\Users\wangyl\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\wangyl\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "E:/master/project/try1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\wangyl\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\wangyl\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\wangyl\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\wangyl\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\wangyl\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
```

Error message:

> **ImportError:**  Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
>   If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes
>   all files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
>
> **Original error was:**
>
> DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I print "activate py27" in cmd and then print "python", it shows "Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda 4.4.0<64-bit> | <default, May 11 2017, 13:17:26> [MSC v.1500 64bit <AMD64>] on win 32", so it means I have python2.7 64bit

Comment: @Omar Einea so what' s the reason?